# Function App Blob Trigger debugging in VS Code failed in Azurite

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azurite

I have created a sample Blobtrigger Azure function and would like to debug it with Azurite in VScode. However it always throws the same error after a debugging session is started.

I am using Azurite for mocking the Blob Service in Azure.

Docker command:

```
docker run -p 10000:10000 -p 10001:10001 -p 10002:10002 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```

The code I have in the repository is as follows:

local.settings.json, with default connection string to Azurite

```
{"IsEncrypted": false,
 "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;"
},
```

__init__.py

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

and function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "cleansed-zone/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

After clicking run and debug in VSCode, an exception is always thrown.

```
 Azure.Core: An error occurred while sending the request.
```

Due to some environment constraints, I could not set up HTTPS on Azurite Docker and not yet able to verify what is the root cause of the error.

Any working setup guidelines for Azurite and Function App local projects would be appreciated.

*Edit: Replace the connectionstring to a Cloud storage account on Azure runs without any issue. Storage explorer also works fine when uploading sample files to Azurite. However docker keep throwing multiple 404 errors when debugging, and failed to create some blob/queues/tables which are compulsory for function apps*

```
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2022:11:22:53 +0000] "HEAD /devstoreaccount1/azure-webjobs-blobtrigger-lex10242-1234567890?comp=metadata HTTP/1.1" 404 
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2022:12:47:49 +0000] "PUT /devstoreaccount1/azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/lez10242-1234567890/WebJobs.Internal.Blobs.Listener?comp=lease HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Hello @Kit Law do you have `Azurite` installed in your vs code..!!

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT Yes..but I had it installed and removed. Docker allows me to view more detailed logs

Comment: Make sure to provide `AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true` and pass for e.g `QueueConnectionString": "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;"`  and then could you please try to debug again

Comment: Same error as before. May I ask why we need a QueueConnectionString for a blob trigger?

Comment: As you are trying it through docker you should run your `cmd` like `docker run -p 10000:10000 -p 10001:10001 -p 10002:10002 \
    mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite` which tells us that which service is associate with a dedicated port .

Comment: Yes I am running it through docker and other functionalities are working well including Azure Storage Explorer. I just realized some blobs does not exist in my container, and I have updated some error messages.

Comment: I have configured as told you earlier , and getting `127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2022:14:14:04 +0000] "PUT /devstoreaccount1/azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/xxxxxxxz-xxxx1250/host?comp=lease HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241212/discussion-between-ajaykumarghose-mt-and-kit-law).

Answer (score 0):

We have tried in our local to use Azurite and it works as expected .

To do that installed following perquisite in our local:

Docker (Docker Installation for Windows , Docker Installation for Linux )

Azure Storage Explorer

Azure Functions Core Tools

Python
Once the complete setup is done make sure you have added the following in your local `settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "QueueConnectionString": "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;"
  }
}
```

And add the following in your function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "the container name which we created in storage explorer",
      "connection": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Then run your application by using `func start`

Here is the OUTPUT for reference:
[image]

For complete setup please refer this [**`BLOG`**](https://medium.com/cloudfordummies/local-azure-storage-emulation-with-azurite-and-azure-functions-a-dummies-guide-53949f0c1f44)